# How to enrich data from custom react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my React application I have created a custom hook which returns a set of data wherever used.

It's used like `const projects = useProjects();`

It's an array of objects , we can assume it looks like this :

```
 [{project_id : 123 , name : 'p1'} , {project_id : 1234 , name : 'p2'} ]
```

Now I need to enrich this data with data from an API. So i have to loop through projects and basically add a new field to each object, so the new array of objects will look like this :

```
[{project_id : 123 , name : 'p1' field3: 'api data'} , {project_id : 1234 , name : 'p2' , field3: 'api data1' } ]
```

How can I achieve this ?

What I did was loop through the projects data and directly added the field inside the loop. But I dont know if i should be mutating this data like that ? I was hoping to see if this is good practice or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few ways you could solve this - it all depends on how you're getting the data back from the API. If you want to have that injected into the hook, you could do something like this -

```
const DEFAULT_PROJECTS = [
    { project_id : 123, name: 'p1' }, 
    { project_id : 1234, name: 'p2' },
];

const useProjects = (dataFromApi) => {
    // Assuming that dataFromApi is what you got back from your API call, 
    // and it's a dictionary keyed on the project_id.
    return useMemo(() => {
        return DEFAULT_PROJECTS.map(proj => {
            const extraData = dataFromApi.get(proj.project_id) || {};
            
            return {
                ...proj,
                ...extraData,
            };
        });
    }, [dataFromApi]);
};
```

The `useMemo` here isn't super helpful if the `dataFromApi` is always changing - it will just rebuild the returned object every time.

If you wanted to get the data as part of your hook, you do something like this -

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const DEFAULT_PROJECTS = [
  { project_id : 123, name: 'p1' },
  { project_id : 1234, name: 'p2' },
];

const useProjects = () => {
  const [dataFromApi, setDataFromApi] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!dataFromApi) return;

    // Simulate the data fetch
    const fetchData = async () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const map = new Map();
          map.set(123, { 
            field3: 'api data',
            field4: 'other data',
          });

          setDataFromApi(map);
        }, 2000);
      });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [dataFromApi]);

  return useMemo(() => {
    let extraData = dataFromApi || new Map();

    return DEFAULT_PROJECTS.map(proj => {
      const extraFields = extraData.get(proj.project_id) || {};

      return {
          ...proj,
          ...extraFields,
      };
    });
  }, [dataFromApi]);
}

export default useProjects;
```

[Here's a code sandbox that shows it in action.](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-leakey-zyrj9?file=/src/useProjects.js)